# Is it possible to get custom object from spring application properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to get own object from application.yaml and bind it with @Value to my component?

Model:

```
@Data
public class CurrencyPlan {
    private String id;
    private String basePrice;
    private String merchantId;
}
```

application.yml:

```
plans:
  eur:
    id: id
    basePrice: 5
    merchantId: someid
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
@Value("${plans.eur}") CurrencyPlan eurPlan
```

What I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'plans.eur' in value "${plans.eur}"
```

Is this even possible? And if so, how to do it? I'm pretty out of ideas :(

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: What if you rename `application.yaml` to `application.yml`? Just a guess, since the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) mentions the `.yml` extension.

Comment: Sorry, it is application.yml, I did a typo while creating question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking to bind your properties to a class you can use `@ConfigurationProperties`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

`@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="plans.eur")` and 
`@Component` would be placed on the `CurrencyPlan`. `@EnableConfigurationProperties` preferably placed on an `@Configuration` class.

After you can autowire the `CurrencyPlan` class into the dependent classes.

Comment: But is there a way to inject is just as an normal object and not a component? Seems weird to me to have that kind of class as a component

Comment: You mean not managed by spring? No. You can remove the component aspect if you read the section from the documentation when it starts talking about `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation but it will always be a spring managed bean to do this.

Comment: Ok, I gave it some more thought and this solution is something I was looking for, thanks :)